# CentOS 6 missing dependencies for default PHP

Tags: php, yum, centos6, dependencies

I have a brand new Dedi install of CentOS 6 x86_64, nothing has been done to it but install rpmforge and htop. Other than that we are default, well as default as GoDaddy gives which is garbage ha ha.

I am trying to install things for PHP but everytime I do I get dependency problems, I am figuring it's something GoDaddy did to it:

```
# yum install php-fpm.x86_64 php-pgsql.x86_64
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-fpm.x86_64 0:5.3.3-22.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-22.el6 for package: php-fpm-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
---> Package php-pgsql.x86_64 0:5.3.3-22.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-22.el6 for package: php-pgsql-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-fpm-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-22.el6
           Installed: php-common-5.3.16-9.x86_64 (@mh-base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.16-9
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-22.el6
Error: Package: php-pgsql-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-22.el6
           Installed: php-common-5.3.16-9.x86_64 (@mh-base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.16-9
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-22.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I've tried `yum clean all` and re-doing but still no go.

**EDIT**

```
# yum repolist all
repo id                                                         repo name                                                                      status
base                                                            CentOS-6 - Base                                                                enabled: 6,381
centosplus                                                      CentOS-6 - Plus                                                                enabled:    21
contrib                                                         CentOS-6 - Contrib                                                             disabled
extras                                                          CentOS-6 - Extras                                                              enabled:    12
rpmforge                                                        RHEL 6 - RPMforge.net - dag                                                    enabled: 4,597
rpmforge-extras                                                 RHEL 6 - RPMforge.net - extras                                                 enabled:   685
rpmforge-testing                                                RHEL 6 - RPMforge.net - testing                                                disabled
updates                                                         CentOS-6 - Updates                                                             enabled:   270
repolist: 11,966
```

**EDIT2**

```
# yum list php-common
Installed Packages
php-common.x86_64                                                              5.3.16-9                                                              @mh-base
```

Comment: post a `yum repolist all` please.

Comment: and a `yum list  php-common` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `php-fpm` is only available in base while a later version of `php-common` is available from a third-party repo. In order to install `php-fpm` you will need to either install the `php-common` package from base or find a `php-fpm` package with the same version number as your current `php-common` elsewhere. In any case the version numbers need to match.

Comment: I was going to answer the same thing, basically I'll just add that it might originate from CentALT repo (your @mh-base labelled repo),  http://centos.alt.ru/repository/centos/

Answer (score 1):

You installed a manually downloaded package from a third party repository, but you don't have the third party repository installed. If you wish to use that third party repository, you should install its repository configuration so that you can automatically install packages from it. I have no idea *which* repository that is, though.